# Foreign key to a table not managed by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I want to create a table using SQLAlchemy that has a foreign key to a table not managed by SQLAlchemy.  The reason is that this database is used by many different applications.  Other applications do need this mapping, but the Python application doesn't.  Is there any way to let SQLAlchemy proceed with creation of a table even without declaring other models (there are about dozen of other models I'd have to declare just to make SQLAlchemy validator happy).

I've tried:

```
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

but this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: So simply defining a [table mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) (not a class) for the table in SQLAlchemy is not an option?

Comment: @GChorn it's not ideal... because this implies I need to have SQL connection to create it (this would add complexity to testing), but if this is the only way, I think I could live with it.

Comment: @GChorn well... actually, it makes no difference. SQLAlchemy won't create the table either way.

Comment: @GChorn OK, finally a combination of "classical" mapping, reflection and some vendor-dependent code to make primary keys unsigned made it work.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution =)